# How to get Spinning Progress Bar at starting of Application

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, spinning

i am new in android. I managed to parse JSON file to my application. Now i want to use AsyncTask to get Spinning progressBa untill application starts and load data. I tried to read many things, but they only give how to get progressbar on onclick events or for downloading events.

This is my code...

I just confused about how to  start progressbar at starting of your application and which part of following code goes to which method of asycTask class....

```
package com.demojson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ListActivity;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static String url = "http://timepasssms.com/webservices/ws.php?type=category";

    private static final String TAG_DATA = "DATA";

    private static final String TAG_0 = "0";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_1 = "1";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_2 = "2";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_3 = "3";
    private static final String TAG_NEW_NAME = "new_name";
    private static final String TAG_4 = "4";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";

    JSONArray jArray = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contents = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONMethod metObj = new JSONMethod();
        JSONObject jOb = metObj.getUrl(url);
        try {
            jArray = jOb.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject child = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String tag_0 = child.getString(TAG_0);
                String id = child.getString(TAG_ID);
                String tag_1 = child.getString(TAG_1);
                String name = child.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String tag_2 = child.getString(TAG_2);
                String description = child.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                String tag_3 = child.getString(TAG_3);
                String new_name = child.getString(TAG_NEW_NAME);
                String tag_4 = child.getString(TAG_4);
                String status = child.getString(TAG_STATUS);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(TAG_NAME , name);

                contents.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contents,
                R.layout.list_items, new String[] { TAG_NAME },
                new int[] { R.id.tvName });
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // --To get listview set...-- 

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String item = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).getText().toString();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }); 
    }


}
```

and JSONMethod Class...

```
package com.demojson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONMethod {
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj=null;
    String json = "";



    public JSONObject getUrl(String url){
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpRespone = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespone.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ue){

        }catch(ClientProtocolException ce){ 

        }catch(IOException ie){

        }

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;
            while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line + "/n"); 
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("JSONMethod", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
        }
        try{
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("JSONMethod", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;
    }
}
```

here is xml files...
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/timepasssms" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_edge"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#DF7401"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can simply use ProgressDialog in onPreExecute() and onPostExecute methods of asynctask..just start it in preExecute method and close it in PostExecute method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using Async class and in doInBackground() method load your List view.

This is how to call Async Class

```
new LoadListView(this).execute(listView);
```

And here is your Async Class

```
public class LoadListView extends AsyncTask<ListView> {


private Context context;
public loadListView(Context context) 
{
    this.context = context;


}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

    //Here you need to load your ListView
    return null;

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

     //Show progress bar here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
    //Hide Progress Bar Here
}
```

It will automatically hide progress bar when listview is loaded..

Answer (score 1):

here is example `

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object table) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(table);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=ProgressDialog.show(Yourclass.this, "Loading Data.", "Please Wait");
    }
```

`
I hope would be helpful

Comment: Its helpful..but i want to know that how can i decide that my application has loaded the listView and now i should call onPostExecute method?

Comment: How I did this is, I created a invisible button and used performClick() of that button once the listview is populated. In the button click I am populating the spinner ..which will be only called after the listview is populated

Comment: It should work, as I implemented same thing recently..where are you facing problem...explain our error, will try to help..