# How to display progress screen while restarting app?

Tags: android

I do app restart with the following intent:

```
Intent restartIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(restartIntent);
```

But there is "white" screen while restarting.

I want to display custom screen instead, while restarting app.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar

Comment: @Wojtek Provided link is about progress bar component. I need to display custom screen while restarting app.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133118/run-progress-bar-while-switching-activity and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153345/how-to-get-spinning-progress-bar-at-starting-of-application

Comment: @MatteoUgolotti thanks, it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Spinning Progress Bar at starting of Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153345/how-to-get-spinning-progress-bar-at-starting-of-application)

Comment: @WojtekT my question is not about displaying progress bar while loading data but about displaying separate screen while restarting app

Comment: You probably can't display animating progress but you can create splashscreen. It will style white window which you have while restarting app. Check this https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565 and this https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't display animating progress but you can create splashscreen. It will style white window which you have while restarting app. Check [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565) and [this](http://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd)

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the **white screen** which is because of android's cold start, and appears when the app loads to memory, you can add the following style item to your `AppTheme`.

```
 <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Now, In your `MainActivity` startup, you can display `progressBar` or anything like placeholder View while your data is being loaded in background and once loaded, hide progress/placeholders etc. You can also create an intermediate Activity/View something like `SplashScreen` to be displayed on `restart Intent` instead of using `progressBar` in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me to get rid of white screen before launching screen for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by clearing the stack manually with `finishAffinity()`:

```
Intent restartIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(restartIntent);
finishAffinity();
```

This way, the transition to your MainActivity does not show the blank screen for a short lapse of time.
If you want a loading screen, you can go to an Activity with the ProgressBar and use this code in that Activity's `onCreate`.

I know it is not the best solution but it is the only way I could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To set a background drawable while an activity is starting you should use something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.SplashTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

as the activity's theme. It will show given drawable instead of the white screen.